# Triggering Appium testing scripts in IOS/Android

Tags: automated-testing, mobile, appium

I am new to mobile automation. I need to know the ways we can achieve triggering automation scripts.

1. Need to trigger my testing scripts when mobile OS is upgraded.
2. Need to trigger my testing scripts when my app is upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

You should integrate your tests in to a continuous integration pipeline, and then you can automatically trigger the tests whenever there is a code change to your source code.

Comment: Bruce McLeod...Thanks for your reply......
But my scenario is little different. Whenever my app is upgraded in my mobile that time it should trigger the test script. Same way for mobile OS upgrades in mobile.

Comment: Do you mean on the device itself, or whenever an updated operating system is released ?

Comment: Still, you can push OS and App updates from a CI-like framework and then schedule your script to run. It will be more manageable and predictable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it via Appium since it doesn't have any control over the functionality of the app so 2 options I think might work:

1. Publish a special version of the app which triggers a job when it got updated. Obv, it is a special version only for testing purposes.
2. Make & install a 2nd app which check and trigger if your targeted app got updated.